# How to Reverse Order of Rows in a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I'm trying to reverse the order of the rows in a tensor that I create. I have tried with tensorflow and pytorch. Only thing I have found is the torch.flip() method. This does not work as it reverses not only the order of the rows, but also all of the elements in each row. I want the elements to remain the same. Is there an array operation of this to index the integers? For instance:

```
 tensor_a = [1, 2, 3]
       [4, 5, 6]
       [7, 8, 9]

I want it to be returned as:
       [7, 8, 9]
       [4, 5, 6]
       [1, 2, 3]

 however, torch.flip(tensor_a) = 
       [9, 8, 7]
       [6, 5, 4]
       [3, 2, 1]
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

According to [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flip.html) `torch.flip` has argument `dims`, which control what axis to be flipped. In this case `torch.flip(tensor_a, dims=(0,))` will return expected result. Also `torch.flip(tensor_a)` will reverse all tensor, and `torch.flip(tensor_a, dims=(1,))` will reverse every row, like `[1, 2, 3] --> [3, 2, 1]`.

Comment: Is there an alternative to torch flip which simply returns a view of the tensor without actually creating another tensor and copying the data?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the performance of the solution I have, but you can do something as follow:

```
import torch
y = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

# Uncomment the next two lines so u can see it works on GPU as well
# device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
# y.to(device)

y = y[[2, 1, 0], :]
# y = y[::-1, :] # this works in numpy but not in pytorch :(
print(y)
```

You can check `numpy` documentation on Slicing and Advanced Indexing for similar examples. Hope this helps.